# Cat6 cable test LED mapping

Tags: cable, cat6, cable-tester

I have a cat6 wired home network and have been trying to replace the jack for one of the cables but there seem to be an issue. When I use the cable tester, I see this sequence:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6&8, 7, 6&8. I tried redoing it many times and I keep getting the same result. I am guessing there is a short circuit somewhere, but not sure how the coloured cables map to the LEDs. With T568B setup, is there a standard mapping to the coloured cables that I can use to figure out which two cables are short circuiting? I can keep removing the cables 1 by 1 and add them back, but there is not much cable left outside of the wall so I do not want to keep cutting them out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A Google image search for "t568b" will show you plenty of images with the information you are after.

6 is Solid Green
8 is solid Brown.

I hope Im wrong but it sounds like someone has damaged the cable in the wall (maybe with a staple / nail?  Either that or the wires have been stripped which would be very wrong technique.)

Comment: I know in t568b the order of cables are:
1: striped orange
2: orange
3: striped green
4: blue
5: striped blue
6: green
7: striped brown
8: brown
Do you mean the 1-8 LED represent the health of 1-8 cables, **respectively**? In which case it makes sense if solid green and solid brown are short circuiting somewhere

Comment: Yes, the 1-8 on the standard cable testers represent the respective pins.